# How to Migrate Users to CRM Online using SCRIBE?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, scribe-workbench

Can you migrate system users prepared in staging database to CRM 2013 Online using SCRIBE?

I need to create 750 users (currently in CRM4) in CRM online and assign them to their source BUs. (Root BU excepted). I can stage them as required.

Can I migrate these users?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create users to a CRM Online using Scribe, you can only update them.

I have this issue recently and my solution was:

1. Create a DTS to create an CSV file* with the users: You can add the users using the Office portal or through the PowerSehll.
2. Creates a DTS with all the other information about the users (The CSV is pretty basic, so you will need to add all the other information related to every user).
3. Create a DTS with the relation between Users and Roles

*You can see the csv format in your Office portal, under Users->Active Users->Bulk add

https://portal.office.com/default.aspx#@/UserManagement/ImportFile.aspx?refer=%2FEAdmin%2FUser%2FActiveUsers16.aspx

Maybe there is a quicker way to do it, but this was the approach I found.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Scribe Insight isn't able to change a users business unit.

When I had a similar requirement (to update the business units of a large number of users) I uses SQL Server Integration Services.

Mike